# PHP DOMNode::C14N() omits root element's second namespcae

Tags: php, xml, xml-signature, canonicalization

I am trying to validate an XML message that is signed using XMLDSig. In order to create a message digest, I need to canonicalize the message first. It works fine, except that DOMNode::C14N() removes the second namespace from the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><DirectoryRes xmlns="http://www.idealdesk.com/ideal/messages/mer-acq/3.3.1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" version="3.3.1">
    <createDateTimestamp>2012-10-29T17:04:56.374Z</createDateTimestamp>
    <Acquirer>
        <acquirerID>0050</acquirerID>
    </Acquirer>
    <Directory>
        <directoryDateTimestamp>2012-10-29T17:04:56.374Z</directoryDateTimestamp>
        <Country>
            <countryNames>Deutschland</countryNames>
            <Issuer>
                <issuerID>NLINGB2U152</issuerID>
                <issuerName>Issuer Simulator</issuerName>
            </Issuer>
        </Country>
    </Directory>
</DirectoryRes>
```

Canonicalizing the XML above results in the following XML:

```
<DirectoryRes xmlns="http://www.idealdesk.com/ideal/messages/mer-acq/3.3.1" version="3.3.1">
    <createDateTimestamp>2012-10-29T17:04:56.374Z</createDateTimestamp>
    <Acquirer>
        <acquirerID>0050</acquirerID>
    </Acquirer>
    <Directory>
        <directoryDateTimestamp>2012-10-29T17:04:56.374Z</directoryDateTimestamp>
        <Country>
            <countryNames>Deutschland</countryNames>
            <Issuer>
                <issuerID>NLINGB2U152</issuerID>
                <issuerName>Issuer Simulator</issuerName>
            </Issuer>
        </Country>
    </Directory>
</DirectoryRes>
```

The remote server I am testing with keeps this namespace when calculating the message digest, so validation obviously fails. I confirmed this issue by first adding the namespace back in before creating my own digest to compare to the digest embedded in the message (the signature was stripped from the XML code above prior to posting). The code however has to work with different servers, some of which may or may not add namespaces (they are not part of the specifications, but as far as I know just adding a redundant namespace declaration shouldn't hurt). I looked this up in the [W3C XML C14N specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n#SuperfluousNSDecl) and they say root elements should always keep their namespaces, except empty default namespaces. The disappearing namespace is neither the default, nor empty, so I am not sure whether this is a bug in DOMNode::C14N() or whether I overlooked something important.

Answer (score 0):

The c14n spec [suggests that extra namespaces don't make it into the canonicalized form](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n#SuperfluousNSDecl).
If you made use of ns2, etc they should make it down into the document emitted by ->c14n.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already figured this out, but since you are communicating with iDEAL you have to follow their "Signing iDEAL messages" remarks:

> For the purpose of generating the digest of the main message, the inclusive canonicalization algorithm must be used<sup>6</sup>. This method of canonicalization of the main message is not (always) explicitly indicated in the iDEAL XML messages. For this reason this transform has not been included in the example messages in this document. Merchants are not required to explicitly indicate this transform in their messages.

**Source:** https://www.pronamic.eu/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/06/Merchant-Integration-Guide-v3-3-1-ENG-February-2015.pdf

This can be confusing since the `CanonicalizationMethod` element algorithm is `http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#`. For the digest however you always have to use `https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315`. This canonicalization method algorithm will also leave the `xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"` in place.

In the `xmlseclibs` library, used a lot for iDEAL, is the  `http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315` canonicalization method algorithm the default:

https://github.com/simplesamlphp/xmlseclibs/blob/v1.3.2/xmlseclibs.php#L872